# missing template processor ember

Tags: ember.js

Very new on using ember (and a js framework in general)
i'm following the official guide on the ember site, installed the ember-cli and create a test app but when i 'server' it a get this message:

```
Missing template processor
Error: Missing template processor 
at module.exports.preprocessTemplates C:\Users\vittorio\AppData\Roaming\npm \node_modules\ember-cli\lib\preprocessors.js:164:11)
at EmberApp._processedTemplatesTree (C:\Users\vittorio\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\broccoli\ember-app.js:567:10)
at EmberApp.appAndDependencies (C:\Users\vittorio\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\broccoli\ember-app.js:808:24)
at EmberApp.javascript (C:\Users\vittorio\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\broccoli\ember-app.js:882:34)
at EmberApp.toArray (C:\Users\vittorio\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\broccoli\ember-app.js:1248:10)
at EmberApp.toTree (C:\Users\vittorio\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\broccoli\ember-app.js:1270:30)
at Object.<anonymous> (e:\web\apps\test_ember\Brocfile.js:20:22)
at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
```

I could not find easy enough info for a beginner and i'm just stuck.

Some info about my environment on windows 7:

```
$ ember --version
version: 0.2.3
node: 0.12.0
npm: 2.7.6
```

Comment: Are you saying that `ember new testtest && cd testtest && ember serve` is producing this error?

Comment: yes, that's exactly what i did based on ember official guide

Comment: Might be worth doing a `bower cache clean` and `npm cache clean`, then forcing an update of ember-cli by doing `npm install -g ember-cli`.  That failing, I would try using node `0.10.36`.  I've been having trouble with the new versions, so I would try the lastest patches of 0.10, 0.11, and 0.12 to see if you have some luck.  You might try https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows to make it easier for you.

Comment: @mpowered Great..cache cleaning and reinstalling ember-cli worked!

Comment: Awesome!  Made it an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ember-cli` projects can be finicky about its module versions. Try to update your package caches and reinstall `ember-cli`:

```
bower cache clean && npm cache clean && npm install -g ember-cli
```

Answer (score 7):

I case anyone else is getting the same error when trying "ember server" command and the solution above doesn't work (didn't work for me). I realized I had to run:

```
npm install
bower install
```

before running the server; after doing this I was able to run "ember server" and worked good.